# Integrate with Google. How to change default account?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

It is really hard to install the same Marketplace app for a few different domains(users).
Google Multiple Sign Ins do not allow you to change google account during app installation process at the Marketplace side. It always using your default account.(first account)

Is there some easy way to change default google account for Marketplace? 
Or maybe it possible to restrict Marketplace installation for some domain?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to cause this problem? Are you talking about admin installs or end-user installs? From standalone pages or from within the Admin Console?

Comment: Yes. I am talking about admin installs from Chrome web store(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xxxxx). Our app has a specific architect and the same app user needs authorize at least 2 domains.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up Marketplace with Google web Store. For app installation we currently pointing our users to Chrome web Store(and it doesn't allow to change account). But our app is also available at the Marketplace by old url like https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId?=xxxx. Both these app are connected currently. Old Marketplace page - has a switch account link. Should we point our users to the Marketplace page for app installation instead of Google Web chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the new Google Apps Marketplace stand-alone pages (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xxxxx) don't handle multi-login correctly. It's a known issue that we are aware of, but no timeline on when it will be fixed. There are no good workarounds, except asking your users to temporarily stop using multi-login when installing your app.